# How to replace leading zero with spaces

Tags: javascript

I have requirement to replace the leading zero with spaces in number in javascript function. Need to make sure the prior spaces in number are retained. For e.g. if my string value is defined as `"   004590808"` then my output should come as 
`"     4590808"`.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Loop through string and if next element is > 0 change current

Comment: Did you try any thing..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function which take the length for the wanted replacement.

```js
var string = '   004590808',
    replaced = string.replace(/^\s*0+/, ({ length }) => ' '.repeat(length));
    
console.log(string);
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: You forgot the leading spaces (I know, not obvious in the posted question but there to read in the text) See my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not clear because you had not wrapped the strings in backticks

We need the function because the regex finds both 00 and needs to convert to the same length in whatever - here spaces. I use "*" for visibility

```js
var s = "   004590808";
s = s.replace(/^\s+0+/,function (z) { return z.replace(/0/g,"*")});

console.log(
  ">" +
  s +
  "<", s.length);
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Solution works for me... What is good reference / guide to write regex..